# WCF web service not performing serialization properly

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-3, serialization

i have the WCF web service within my solution. service has interface which implemeted in service class. i added few new methods in interface as well as implemented in service class. i can access if i use the sevice dll reference to my asp.net mvc 3 application. but after deployment and adding the service reference of service i am unable to get the newly added methods. by creating the client object . why should this happening? I deployed service at remote server.

I checked in wsdl also, but could not found metadata about the newly added methods.

**Edited:** 
Well well well... I don't know what happened and somehow i got the serialized objects what i expected now. but when i am performing any operation with these objects I am getting problem that unable to connect to service.

```
    "An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://MyServer/MyAdminService.svc.
 This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol.
 This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server 
(possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details."

Inner Exception: 

"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive"
```

why should this? what are the necessary attributes int he web.config need to establish the connection between clent and server objects ?

**Resolved:**
http://lalitcdhake.blogspot.com/2011/10/serialization-with-entity-framework-4.html

Cheers

Comment: Can you add the datacontract definition to your question please.

Comment: This is usually happening if your deployment went wrong. IIS-Reset after deployment, did you deploy into the GAC or localy? We need more information about your solution. Otherwise it is nearly impossible to give you an answer!

Comment: ok... i have windows server 2008 with iis 7. it is deployed locally on server. but is that affects to serialization of methods really to locate service in GAC or locally ?

Comment: please guys , help me for out of this ... :(

Comment: ok, so if wsdl does not contain metadata about new methods, it means that service reference can't be generated right and we need to look before that. so, deployment, could you compare dll's that are on website path with build output dlls?

Comment: if you have added newly class to the service check if all of them are marked "Serializable".

Comment: is it necessary to use "serializable" attribute with methods really ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://lalitcdhake.blogspot.com/2011/10/serialization-with-entity-framework-4.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you marked new methods with OperationContract attribute? Sample from msdn:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="Microsoft.WCF.Documentation")]
  public interface ISampleService{
    // This operation specifies an explicit protection level requirement.
    [OperationContract]
    string SampleMethod(string msg);
  }

  class SampleService : ISampleService
  {
  #region ISampleService Members

  public string  SampleMethod(string msg)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Called with: {0}", msg);
      return "The service greets you: " + msg;
  }

  #endregion
  }
```

Comment: where ? in service code or in interface i need to use this attribute?

Comment: interface, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontractattribute.aspx

Comment: infact yes i am having the ServiceContract in interface and methods with OprationContract.

Comment: in such case looks like deployment problem.

Comment: yes, i added these attributes already, infact it come by default. any guessing for serialization ...?

Comment: try to delete all file on remote server and re-deploy all the service. On the client try to right-click on service reference and select "update reference.."

Comment: can you just explain me what is binding and end points in wcf...in fact i am new in this subject... i can read from net ... but i need quick though for the same...

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a deployment issue.  Some things to try.

1. Confirm your methods are available in your local wsdl.  If the methods are available locally your problem has nothing to do with serialization.
2. Confirm the remote server you deployed to is in fact what you are looking at when you check the remote wsdl.  There are many ways to do this but a simple one would be to introduce an error into web config and confirm the app goes down (if this is a dev server and taking down the app is not harmful).